# How to hide all windows except the one that I'm using?

Tags: linux, gnome3, fedora-20

I have set a shortcut to hide all the windows with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

But now I would like to set one that hides all except the currently active window. Is that possible?

Comment: Hey, see [`this`](http://askubuntu.com/a/40082/207566) in AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 7 this is possible with the Windows Key + Home or by clicking and holding the title bar of the active application and "shaking" it (known as Aero Shake). As Sunstreaker pointed out, dv3500ea on AskUbunutu has a wonderful, albeit long, set of instructions to do so in Ubuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40022/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-minimizing-all-windows-except-the-active-one/40082#40082).